# FirePath tab not appearing in Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug, firepath

I am facing this issue in FF ver. 24.0. I installed firebug version - 1.12.4  and installed the FirePath version 0.9.7. I am unable to see the FirePath tab in the Firebug panel when pressed F12. I tried to install Firebug version 1.11.4 and found the same issue. Could anyone let me know on how to enable this tab?

Thanks & Regards,
Rashmi

Answer (score 4):

Hi I am using firefox Version 51.0.1 and faced the similar issue.
The property which I used to get back  the Firepath and Firefinder under firebug is =

browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = false

Steps:

1. Open firefox
2. Type about:config  in the  explorer
3. click on the I uderstand button
4. Now in the search box enter "browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2" (without quotes) and hit enter
5. Set the value as false ( you need to click the property to toggle the values)
6. close the firefox and open again
7. Launch firebug ...Now you should see your fire path and firefinder back

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me using Firefox 25.0/28.0a1 + Firebug 1.12.4 + FirePath 0.9.7 on Win7.

So it may probably be caused either by another extension or by some preference in your profile. You should [create a new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), just install Firebug and FirePath there and see if it's then working.

Also, if you see any errors related to Firebug, you should post them to the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug) or if there are some related to FirePath, you should [create a new issue in their issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/firepath/issues/list).

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

In my case  , I have to change two things in Firefox about:config page.

**browser.tabs.remote.autostart    = false

browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = false**

then restart firefox.

This fixed the issue, and enable firepath in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.I installed the FirePath addon separately to Firefox. Now it's working fine. I can see the FirePath tab.

The versions used by me are:
FireFox - 54.0.1
Firebug - 2.0.19

FYI:
The compatibility check for FF and Firebug can be seen at below link
https://addons.mozilla.org/mk/firefox/compatibility/reporter/firebug@software.joehewitt.com?appver=54.0

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to install firebug firepath if you have latest version of Chrome and firefox. you can follow following step to inspect element and for xpath, CSS selector.
1. open url.
2. inspect element(F12).
see Image

[see image for inspect and find xpath & CSS selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvh1T.png)

thank you.